# Azure File Sync can sync between server folder and Blob?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to sync a storage folder on my server with a folder on my Blob storage. Does Azure File Sync now sync files between VMs and Blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Azure File Sync only supports that centralize your organization's file shares in Azure Files. It can not `sync a storage folder on my server with a folder on my Blob storage`.

You may raise your idea in the [user feedback of azure storage site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage).